# C2664 cannot convert parameter 1 from from User *const to User in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to C++ and Qt, but I have been playing around with it for a couple of days and I need to come up with a basic prototype of my product by Friday, so there is not much time to convert my 7 years of PHP knowledge into C++ knowledge, as I am sure that it takes a lifetime to master C++. I am getting stuck from time to time in the last couple of days due to non-existing knowledge about the small bits and bytes. At this time I have even no idea what to look for on the Internet.

First of all, I am using Qt as my framework to do a simple GUI network client that can talk to my PHP application. I wanted to create a very simple WebAPI class in this application and have the class "webapi". The scenario is very simple, the user starts the application and the applications checks if the user is logged in or not. If not, then it opens up a login dialog. After entering the information (username / password) into the dialog the user object is filled and the method "authenticate" is called.

The authenticate method then calls the `fUser` method in the webapi class to make a request to the server holding some information to authenticate the user against the server's database.

In code it looks like this:
Savor.cpp:

```
user = new User();

    while ( user->isLoggedIn() != true )
    {
        LoginDialog loginWindow;
        loginWindow.setModal(true);
        int result = loginWindow.exec();
        if ( result == QDialog::Accepted )
        {
            user->authenticate(loginWindow.getUsername(), loginWindow.getPassword());

            if ( !user->isLoggedIn() )
            {
                loginWindow.setUsername(loginWindow.getUsername());
                loginWindow.exec();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            exit(1);//exit with code 1
        }
    }
```

User.cpp:

```
void User::authenticate(QString username, QString password)
{
    qDebug() << username;
    qDebug() << password;


    if ( username != "" && password != "")
    {

        webapi wapi;
        loggedIn = wapi.fUser(this);
    }
    else
    {
        loggedIn = false;
    }
}
```

webapi.cpp:

```
/**
  Represents the fUser method on the server,
  it wants to get a user object
  the user will need to be authenticated with this
  then all infos about user are transfered (RSA Keypair etc)
 * @brief webapi::fUser
 * @param username
 * @param password
 * @return User
 */
bool webapi::fUser(User baseUser)
{
    return true;
}
```

Now you can clearly see that I am not doing anything at the moment in the `webapi::fUser` method. In fact, I am not even returning what I would like to return. Instead of a boolean I would like to return a User object, actually the same that I got in the first place through the parameter. However, i get a copy constructor error when I do that. (In my `savor.h` file I have declared a private attribute as a pointer => `User *user;`)

So the question is, what am I doing wrong when I call the `fUser` method? Why can I not simply pass the user object itself to the method ? I have not got around to fully understand `const`, and pointers and when to use what.

With Qt creator I actually use the MS Visual C++ compiler which throws the error as in the title:

> **C2664 'webapi::fUser' : cannot convert paramter 1 from 'User *const' to 'User'**

I have read [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5b150wd(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5b150wd%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) this page explaining when this happens, the only solutions is the conversion of the object itself.

If thats the case I might approach the entire problem in the wrong way.

I am looking forward to your tips and help on this matter.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`webapi::fuser` takes a `User` by value, but you are passing it a `User*` here:

```
wapi.fUser(this);
```

Either pass a `User`:

```
wapi.fUser(*this);
```

or change `webapi` to take a pointer to `User`.